# Halal Income from haram source

Tags: money, halal-haram

several years ago i used to do youtube adsense. where i review anime / film. the anime is very unislamic. i get money from reviewing that so it's haram money.

one day i decided to use that money to buy laptop. with that laptop, i learn how to code or doing programming. and then i made several apps / program, which generated lot of money.

now i am confused whether my income is halal or not. the work i am doing now is halal insyaAllah, but the laptop, which is used to make application, is bought using haram money.

is the profit / income i made all haram, and the apps too ?

Comment: Give out the amount that laptop was worth in Sadaqah. Ask Allah's forgiveness. Continue. Life doesn't stop. Remember, the income generated from the apps, will be attributed to the apps alone, regardless of what enabled you to make the apps (the haram money). The haram money from the ad-sense days, you can pay it out in Sadaqah. The rest is yours.